# 301 htaccess redirect with directory wildcard

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

Is there a more efficient way to write these redirects?

```
RewriteRule ^directory/subdir/1990/010190/(.*)$ directory/editorials/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^directory/subdir/1990/020190/(.*)$ directory/editorials/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^directory/subdir/1990/030190/(.*)$ directory/editorials/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^directory/subdir/1990/040190/(.*)$ directory/editorials/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^directory/subdir/1990/050190/(.*)$ directory/editorials/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^directory/subdir/1990/060190/(.*)$ directory/editorials/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It seems like I need a wildcard for the subdirectory of `/1990/`

Being able to do this would greatly decrease the number of redirects I have, making it more manageable. Any help or hints appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single rule for all of those rules:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/subdir/1990/0[1-6]0190/(.*)$ directory/editorials/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Great! You'll get the checkmark, but what if I have directories in place of the 1990, say 1991, 1992, 1993 etc.. The redirect rule removes all of 'subdir/1991/010190/', so would it possible to simply this as well?

Comment: In chat case we could try to use regex alternation like `(1990/010190|1991/020190|1992/020190)`